Setting Up MDP - critical failure -
I tried to setup mdp npcmcpp and for rofi's theme and applet: https://github.com/adi1090x/rofi. It didn't work.
Here's my system info:
francois@LenovoUbuntu ~> neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               francois@LenovoUbuntu
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ---------------------
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 82R9 IdeaPad Flex 5 14ALC7
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.9.3-060903-generic
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 19 mins
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2882 (dpkg), 17 (snap)
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1200
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: i3
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: alacritty
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 4.372GHz
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Lucienne
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Memory: 2609MiB / 15322MiB
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.



francois@LenovoUbuntu ~> screenfetch
                          ./+o+-       francois@LenovoUbuntu
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 6.9.3-060903-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 20m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2891
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: fish 3.3.1
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1920x1200
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   WM: i3
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   GTK Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK3]
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   Disk: 60G / 220G (29%)
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics @ 16x 4.372GHz
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    GPU: RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.57, 6.9.3-060903-generic)
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     RAM: 2883MiB / 15322MiB
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/
                   ````` +oo+++o\:
                          `oo++.

i followed these guides in order:
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/beginner-s-guide-to-setting-up-and-using-mpd/16831
https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-the-mpd-music-server-on-ubuntu-linux
and finally
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8fnYjYe5bU&t=194s
At first I tried to just setup mdp, I had 3 problem, none of which got fixed. So, I'm 5 problem deep (service can'T be started or enable [2]):
When I ran systemctl status mdp.service or  mpd --verbose --stdout --no-daemon: It just hanged "Something state file"
Running journalctl -xeu mpd.service and looking at mdp.log here are some of the errors I got these issues:
The job identifier is 3417.
Jun 19 19:40:29 LenovoUbuntu mpd[9493]: Ignoring the 'pid_file' setting in systemd mode
Jun 19 19:40:29 LenovoUbuntu mpd[9493]: Jun 19 19:40 : exception: Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6601'; Failed to bind socket: Address already in use
Jun 19 19:40:29 LenovoUbuntu systemd[1]: mpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

I also had during the whole time (But it might have been fixed due to using the config from the video:
:
etc/timidity/timidity.cfg doesn't exist. whenever I ran mdp
I installed wildmidi as recommended but it didn't come with it. I couldn't find it only. I installed Timidity-fat and Timidity++ (command promp and source-forge).
Still no timidity.cfg file. IF SOMEONE HAS IT, PLEASE SEND IT
Or explain why it's depracated and the setup to bypass it. My current setup bypass it, but idk why or it's supposed to work.
Even killing it, it seems port 6600 was always used no matter what. Same for port 6601 and when killing it, port 6602 worked.(Idk if some thing used port 6600 and 6601 all the time or if it was a bug where it only worked once per port change.
Then I had:
░░ The job identifier is 3201.
Jun 19 19:30:46 LenovoUbuntu mpd[8510]: Ignoring the 'pid_file' setting in systemd mode
Jun 19 19:30:46 LenovoUbuntu mpd[8510]: exception: failed to open log file "/root/.mpd/mpd.log" (config line 4): No such file or directory
Jun 19 19:30:46 LenovoUbuntu systemd[1]: mpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

where even though this is my config file in "/home/francois/.config/mpd/"
(I fucked arround with ip and port change 6600-6603, localhost-127.0.0.1):
#This file is actually being used

music_directory     "/home/francois/Music/My Music"
playlist_directory  "/home/francois/Music/My Music"


db_file             "/home/francois/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file            "/home/francois/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file            "/home/francois/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file          "/home/francois/.mpd/mpd.mpdstate"


bind_to_address "127.0.0.1"
port "6600"


audio_output {
    type "pulse"
    name "pulse audio"
}
audio_output {
    type                    "fifo"
    name                    "my_fifo"
    path                    "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
    format                  "44100:16:2"
}

I even replaced ~ --> $HOME --> /home/francois to be sure. It still did that.
I tried a bunch and then the sound fucked on my computer. Then I rebooted in i3 and after 30s the mouse fucked. The sound stayed muted. The internet went out.
I went to safe mode, changed the .config files for mdd and rebooted again.
And now all regular functionality are there.
But there's a new bug:
I do this:
/etc/init.d/mpd start
sudo update-rc.d mpd enable

--> Starting mpd (via systemctl): mpd.service.
$mdp-> just hangs there
$ systemtcl start mdp.service  --> Failed to start mdp.service: Unit mdp.service not found.
sudo systemctl enable mdp.service
->Failed to enable unit: Unit file mdp.service does not exist.
now I went back to i3 and:
exception: unable to read the pid from file "/home/francois/.mpd/mpd.pid": No such file or directory ```


Power of Rubber ducking. A part of the problem was found.
It's mdp not mpd!!!!!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

They deleted my previous answer. It was messy, but it did countain the fix.
Tldr:
Update your Kernel.
Then sudo apt update.
Install Timidity with snap or apt or apt get, it should be straight forward now.
Change the port in the settings. 6600 and 6601 might already be used.
Then make it into a user and not a daemon.
Reboot.
